# Elmah logging errors in SQL server but not showing up on Elmah.axd

Tags: error-handling, elmah, error-logging

I have Elmah set up on a WCF application and it is logging to SQL server. Everything seems to be working as far as inserting the data into the `Elmah_error` table. But there are 5 errors in the table and only 2 displayed on `Elmah.axd`.

How can I set Elmah to show all errors that are in the table?

### Extra info

#### Errors in database

- System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
- System.Exception
- System.Exception
- System.ArgumentException

#### Errors displayed on Elmah.axd

- System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException
- System.Web.HttpException

#### Web.config settings

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
  <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
</httpModules>
```

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ELMAH" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Elmah records an application name for each log entry in the Elmar_error table.  When you browse Elmah.axd it uses a default application name to filter the log entries.

You can set the applicationName attribute on the errorLog tag in the elmah Web.config section to view the entries.

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog" applicationName="AppName" />
```

Comment: Just curious; did you find this documented somewhere besides in the Elmah codebase?

Comment: Just saved me a massive headache, 3 apps using the same Elmah database... Thankyou very much

Comment: Thank you for sharing the solution. Worked like charm for me.